# Get Selected Value from Table using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using below code for getting check value from table which is printing all checked checkbox value.But i want to get only selected checkbox value not all checked value.

```
function clickedBoxAdd(checkBoxvalue) {
    var values = new Array();
    $.each($("input[name='" + checkBoxvalue + "']:checked").closest("td").next("td").next("td"),
           function () {
                values.push($(this).text());
           });
           alert(values);   
           addVariablesRow1()  

}
```

For adding table row if i click checkbox using below code which is working.Can anyone please help how to delete rows as well when i unselect checkboxes.

```
function addVariablesRow1() {
            var $t = $("#addTable");
            var $row = $($t.find("tr")[1]);
            var r = $row.clone();
            r.find("input[type=text]").val("")
            r.find("input[type=checkbox]").attr('checked',  false)
            r[0].style.display = "";
            r.appendTo($t);
}
```

HTML

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" name="checkBox_B[]" onclick="clickedBoxAdd(this.name)">
```

Table

```
        <table id="addTable" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
                <tbody class="snmp_oid_table">

        <tr class="info">
          <th>Oid</th>
          <th>Data Type</th>
          <th>Set Value</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
  <tr style="display:none">

            <td>
              <input type="text" class="name" id="oids" name="oid">
            </td>   

            <td>
              <input type="text" class="text" name="oid_description">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" class="expectedValue" name="expected_value">
            </td>
</tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
```

CheckBox

```
         <table id="addOidTable" class="table table-bordered">
           <thead>
         <tr class="info">
           <th style="width: 10px;">
           <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox_add_b[]" onclick="selectAddAll(this)"/>SA</th>
           <th>name</th>
           <th>Oid </th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
         <tbody class="oid_table">
             <% @all_b_oids.each do |oids| %> 
                <tr id="tr_snmp_<%=oids['id'] %>">
                   <td>
                     <input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" name="checkBox_Oid_B[]" onclick="clickedBoxAddAll(this.name)">
                   </td>
                   <td style="word-break:break-all;">
                      <%= oids['name']%>   
                    </td>
                     <td style="word-break:break-all;">
                         <%= oids['oid']%>    
                     </td>
                 </tr>
                 <% end %>
           </tbody>
         </table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `selected checkbox value` ? the last checked value? Also it would be great if we have minimum reproducible example to understand your problem

Comment: yes Kenny.i need last checked value only.

Comment: In this type of questions, a minimum reproducible example is very helpful to understand the problem. As we can't fire dart in dark.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually getting all checkbox's values and pushing those in arrays by using '$.each'

Anyway, for the first part of your question, your checkbox should have a class e.g. `chkbox`, then you can get it's value in it's click handler:

```
 $(".chkbox").click(function() {
$(this).closest('td').html()
});
```

To delete a row from table, assign id to each `tr` once you create it:

```
r.attr("id", "rowid");
```

Then once checkbox is unselected, you can remove row in checkbox's click handler:

```
 $(".chkbox").click(function() {
    if(!$(this).is(':checked')) {
       $('#rowid').remove();

    }
 });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks.$(this).val();is not working.I am getting value as "on".But table value is "Testing"

Comment: that's actually the text not the value, for this try `$(this).next('label').text();`. Also please paste your  checkbox and table html in question for better understanding.

Comment: Please update the question to paste complete input tag for checkbox

Comment: Added.
please check

Comment: In ` <input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" name="checkBox_B[]" onclick="clickedBoxAdd(this.name)">` i can't see any closing tag and text

Comment: i didn't  get Muhammad

Comment: where is that checkbox text "Testing" in html? i can't find

Comment: oh.That is loaded from DB.oid_table

Comment: Oh that's in the `td` if i am not wrong. You can get checkbox's closest td by using .closest() function e.g. `$(this).closest('td').html()`. give it a try

Comment: i am trying this-    var val=$("input[name='" + checkBoxName + "']:checked").closest("td").next("td").next("td").html();

Comment: Getting first row value only if i select any checkbox.If i am using   "var val=$(this).closest("td").next("td").next("td").html();"
,i am getting undefined.